# mongoose model date to view engine in human readable format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

Is there any other way to do this?

I want to pass the date from mongo db schema to the view engine but I am unable to apply any changes to the model.date property all others which are strings can be changed. So I came up with this solution - to add a new property to the passed objects using model js which does not look very good.

```
data.getLatestSixTrips()
            .then((trips) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < trips.length; i += 1) {
                    var newDate = new Date(trips[i].date);
                    trips[i].humanReadableDate = moment(newDate).format("DD-MMM-YYYY (dddd)");
                }

                res.render('home/index', { data: trips });
```

Property in the schema looks like this:

```
date: { type: Date, min: Date.now },
```

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like it's not a model concern, it's a view concern.  Consider doing a view engine based rendering (which varies depending on what your view engine is) for doing the render you want.

Comment: u can use javascript function 4 that